# Good spreader for peat moss

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, overseeding, peat

I'm just wondering if anyone has a good suggestion for an affordable spreader that would work to distribute peat moss? I'm reseeding my lawn, and it's good to spread a fine layer of peat moss over it to keep the moisture in. I've searched for a long time online trying to find a good tool that would work for this, but most spreaders have reviews saying they don't work well for non granulated materials.

I'm also up for other suggestions here, that don't involve peat moss (which is bad for the environment) or a spreader. Thanks!

Comment: I uses cocopeat instead. lasts longer too.

Comment: Instead of peat moss, you can use straw (best if shredded), cheesecloth (if raised a bit above the seedbed) and erosion mat (but get the kind with netting made from plant fibers, not plastic. It's also usually cheaper). The Lawn Institute doesn't recommend a specific seed covering: https://www.thelawninstitute.org/lawn-care-basics/proper-planting/

Comment: i like hand tossing clumps high into the air and letting them rain down uniformly. You can cover a surprisingly large area quickly like this. Cons: It gets you dusty, your arm gets tired, and can't be done in wind. Pros: Highly uniform ovals that are easy to fill-in by hand, cheap/simple, and effective. I also gently rake before and after applying the seed to stir up existing dirt/dust to reduce needed amounts, and rake after the moss to mix it all up; works really well with a bit less bad peat.